# Center a group of features all to the same point

Tags: geojson

Given a group of features in a geojson object, is there a way to translate them, such that they all have the same center? I'd like achieve this in the actual coordinates of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily with GDAL. Here is a test with ogrinfo and GeoJSON file "multipoly.json"

```
C:\temp\poista>ogrinfo multipoly.json -ro -dialect sqlite -sql "select centroid(st_union(geometry))
as geometry from OGRGeoJSON"
INFO: Open of `multipoly.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (170.333333, 202.333333) - (170.333333, 202.333333)
Layer SRS WKT:
Geometry Column = geometry
...
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  POINT (170.33333333333331 202.33333333333331)
```

Seems to work, all multipolygons are unioned firs to one feature with "st_union" and "centroid" is used for finding the middle point. Same query can be used for converting the result into a new GeoJSON file "centroid.json". In real life you would probably like to add more columns into "select".

```
ogr2ogr -f geojson centroid.json multipoly.json -dialect sqlite -sql "select centroid (st_union(geometry)) as geometry from OGRGeoJSON"
```